# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) without increasing autoindex

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I'm running a SQL query, looks a bit like this

```
INSERT INTO people (Name, Role)
VALUES('{$Name}', '{$Occupation')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

The 'people' table has a surrogate ID key as primary, that is set by MySQLs Autoindex.

'Name' and 'Role' is put together as a composite unique key.

Problem is, when I run this query and hit someone with the same name and role, and get their respective ID, the autoindex still increases.

Is it possible to prevent this easily, or do i need to run 2 separate queries to check if already exists and then insert?

Comment: This code looks like it desperately needs to use *placeholder values*. There's a high probability those two things are [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You're also probably going to have to normalize this table and better deal with collisions. What if there's two people named "Dave Taylor" that are both doctors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't worry if the auto-increment increases.  Admittedly, it is aesthetically "ugly", but gaps in the sequence shouldn't matter.  And, the gap could appear for other reasons.

But, if this matters, you can reduce the probability of it happening by checking in the query:

```
INSERT INTO people (Name, Role)
    SELECT name, role
    FROM (SELECT '{$Name}' as name, '{$Occupation}' as role) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM people p WHERE p.name = x.name)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name);  -- no op;
```

You can still get race conditions where gaps might occur, but this makes that much less likely.

Comment: Not really due to aesthetics, simply because of how often the query is ran, I was afraid of potentially hitting the maximum id value within a year, which would become quite the headace.

Thank you, ill try this

Comment: @user3853973 . . . If that is the case, perhaps you should use a `bigint` for the column value.

Answer (score 1):

As mysql documentation on [insert ... on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) says:

> For example, if column a is declared as UNIQUE and contains the value
>   1, the following two statements have similar effect:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
> c=c+1;
>
> UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
> ```
>
> **(The effects are not identical for
>   an InnoDB table where a is an auto-increment column. With an
>   auto-increment column, an INSERT statement increases the
>   auto-increment value but UPDATE does not.)**

So, for innodb tables this is the expected behaviour. Either you choose a different table engine for your table or you cannot use the `on duplicate key update` clause if you do not want your auto increment field to increase in case of an update. Note: there is nothing wrong to have gaps in the sequence of the auto_increment ids. If there is a business requirement of a continuously incrementing serial number, then you should not be using auto increment anyway.

Update:

If you are worried about exhausting the bigint range soon, then use the `uuid()` mysql function or something similar from php to generate the unique ids for you. But unsigned bigint's max range is pretty big...